# How to convert normal date to javascript date

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a date like 2012-08-09T20:37:52.041  i want to subtract this time from the current time. To use the getTime() function and subtract the time i need this time in a parsable format. How do I do that?
Or is there any other way to subtract a time like 2012-08-09T20:37:52.041 from the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *really super hard* to parse dates in JavaScript.

```
var datestring = "2012-08-09T20:37:52.041";
var date = new Date(datestring);
var diff = (new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime(); // in milliseconds
```

I'm joking, it's super easy.

Answer (score 2):

Use a date parsing library like http://www.datejs.com/. With that, you can do this:

```
Date.parse('2012-08-09T20:37:52') // You'll have to remove the milliseconds
```